# c++ Namespace with methods cause `duplicate symbols`

Tags: c++, linker

I have header with namespace, where defined methods and include this header in others. g++ gives `duplicated symbols` error. as for defying vars in namespace everything is ok

header1.h:

```
namespace A {
    void print() {}
}
```

code1.h:

```
#include "header1.h"
```

code2.h:

```
#include "header1.h"
```

compiling:

`g++ -g --std=c++14 -c code1.cpp`

`g++ -g --std=c++14  -c code2.cpp`

Comment: Functions can't be defined in multiple source files. Mark the function `inline` or implement it in only one file.

Comment: @DeiDei Yes, `inline` helped! Thanks a lot!